# How to execute auto test both in linux and windows system with Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework, autotest

Now have a requirement that need test two physical servers, one is linux and the other is windows. I select Robot Framework to do my autotest, most test cases will execute in linux, but some of them must be executed in Windows system, who can tell me how to cover the two types of test with one deployed RF codes? I want to generate only one test report, thanks a lot!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry for ambiguous ask, my detailed description: Generally I want to deploy RF code in a test cilent(which is CentOS) , the SUT(system under test) is also a CentOS server, test cilent will test all cases with SUT through ssh connection, that's a smooth procedure. But now my test cases will extend to test Windows server, which means test client will also interact with Windows server, but I don't know how to reach it.

Comment: What is the interface to communicate with the Windows SUT? If it's again an ssh, then it's just a change in the target host. And if it's not - then it's a different test, isn't it?